# JavaScript recursive loop to sum all integers from nested array

Tags: javascript, for-loop, recursion

> `arr` will be an array, containing integers, strings and/or arrays like itself.  Sum all the integers you find, anywhere in the nest of arrays.

This is what I came up with, but still not right yet

```
function arraySum(arr) {
  var sum = 0;
  var sum1 = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === Math.round(arr[i])) { //check if its an integar
      sum += arr[i];
    }  
    if (arr[i] instanceof Array) {
      for (var n = 0; n < arr[i].length; n++) {
        sum1 += arr[i][n];
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(sum + sum1);
}

var sumArr = [[[[[[[[[1]]]]]]]], 1]; // => 101. SHOULD BE 2
arraySum(sumArr);
```

Comment: it would be simpler to flatten then sum (both one-line operations), and since addition is associative and communicative, the answer will be the same.

Comment: `[[[[[[[[[1]]]]]]]], 1].toString().match(/[\d\.]+/g).map(Number).reduce(function(a,b){return a+b; })`

Comment: I could be wrong, but I feel like you might benefit from changing:
     'if (arr[i] === Math.round(arr[i])) { //check if its an integer '
to 
     'if(arr[i] === math.round(arr[i]) && isNaN(arr[i]) === false) { 
     //check if it's an integer and IS a number. '

Comment: recursive means the function calls itself. Instead of attempting to sum the array (which may have further nested arrays), you should pass the array to `arraySum`, and add the return value to your sum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function arraySum(arr) {
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     if (arr[i] instanceof Array) { sum += arraySum(arr[i]);}
     if (arr[i] === Math.round(arr[i])) {sum += arr[i];}   
  }
 return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

What about using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) recursively?

```
function arrSum(arr) {
    return arr.reduce(function fn(a, b) {
        if (Array.isArray(b)) {
            return b.reduce(fn, a);
        } else if (b === Math.round(b)) {
            return a + b;
        } 

        return a;
    }, 0);
}
```

> The reduce() method applies a function against an accumulator and each
>   value of the array (from left-to-right) has to reduce it to a single
>   value.

Comment: doesn't support ie8, but i will definitely consider using it after finding a cross-browser solution

Comment: See the polyfill at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Answer (score 3):

```
function add(array){
  return(array+"").match(/-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g).reduce(function(a,b) {
    return +a+ +b;
  });
}
```

That uses regex to parse a stringified array but it should work just fine.
So then there'll be an array with only the numbers. Those get parsed into a `.reduce()` which adds them. The best I could think of :)
help from: [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

`function add(n){return JSON.stringify(n).match(/[^\D]+/g).reduce(function(n,r){return 1*n+1*r})}` is what came out of http://jscompress.com

**SPEED: 0.04395800351630896s**
*Either 11% faster than other answers, or my Math's terrible*

A more supported answer:

```
function add (array) {
    var nums = JSON.stringify(array).match(/[\d\-]+/g),
        i,
        sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < nums.length; i += 1) {
        sum += parseInt(nums[i], 10);
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: judging by the edits, i think you mean the best _i_ could think of ;)

Comment: @dandavis ohhh. wow, i used mdn which i found after a quick google search. Updated to show that

Comment: Since we're going with oneliners replace `return parseInt(a,10) + parseInt(b,10);` with **`return a*1 +b*1`;**  to shorten it further..

Comment: or `return +a + +b` to shorten it further

Comment: @user2734550 If you going to be using this functions many times *(more than ten)* I would recommend a fast solution *(this one)* ;)

Comment: @Roamer-1888 for that you will have to use the "alternate" regex mentioned

Comment: I used to write safety critical software and would have been shot for a solution like this.

Comment: Returned NaN when there is string in array. Not working

Comment: @user2734550 can you comment the array? Most problems can be fixed by modifying the regex

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this using recursive functions, try with something like this:

```
function arraySum(arr) {
var sum = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === Math.round(arr[i])) { 
        sum += arr[i];
    }  
    if (arr[i] instanceof Array) {
        sum += arraySum(arr[i]); //This will apply the same function to the current Array element which is an Array
    }
}
return sum; //To have the sum of the actual Array
}
    var sumArr = [[[[[[[[[1]]]]]]]], 1];

console.log(arraySum(sumArr)); //now it returns 2
```

Comment: This is good. Only, the Integer check will fail for strings eg `"5"` due to strict equality check.

Comment: @levi you're right, but since the instruction was to "Sum all the integers you find" I think that's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
function arraySum(arr) {
    return arr.reduce(function(s, n) {
        return s + ((n instanceof Array) ? arraySum(n) : +n || 0);
    }, 0);
}
```

`+n` attempts to convert strings to integers, defaulting to zero if `+n` yields `NaN`.

http://jsfiddle.net/3z7pakfx/

Comment: Good one, it just fails on numerical strings, e.g '1'.

Comment: Yes, me too - so, it should work like this (convert strings to integers)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that doesn't rely on iteration:

```
var arraySum = function(array) {
  if (array.length === 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  var rest = array.slice();
  var next = rest.pop();
  if (next instanceof Array) {
    return arraySum(next) + arraySum(rest);
  } else {
    return next + arraySum(rest);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The sum of any value, `v`, and `more` values is -

1. If we do not have a value, `v`, return the empty sum, `0`
2. *By induction*, we have a value, `v`. If the value is an array, return the sum of `v` plus the sum of `more`
3. *By induction*, we have a value `v` that is not an array. Return the numeric value of `v` plus the sum of `more`

```js
const sum = ([ v, ...more ]) =>
  v === undefined
    ? 0                   // 1
: Array.isArray(v)
    ? sum(v) + sum(more)  // 2
: Number(v) + sum(more)   // 3

const result =
  sum([[[[[[[[[1]]]]]]]], 1])

console.log(result)
// 2
```